# How to get column names from the XML format of a Microsoft Excel document?

Tags: xml, excel

I asked this question earlier today but, sadly, it was marked as a "duplicate" and so it went unanswered. I'll try to rephrase my question.

Assume that I have a Microsoft Excel file, of xlsx format. This involves a few files, all of them XML files. Does anyone know where I can find the names of the columns?

Getting the values of the cells is fairly easy. Let's assume I start with something like this:

```
OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(file);
XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(opc);
SharedStringsTable sst = xssfReader.getSharedStringsTable();
XSSFReader.SheetIterator itr = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator)xssfReader.getSheetsData();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    InputStream sheetStream = itr.next();
    if(itr.getSheetName().equals(sheetName)) {  // Or you can keep track of sheet numbers
        in = sheetStream;
        return;
    } else {
        sheetStream.close();
    }
}
```

"in" is now an InputStream that reads from the XML file. And from that file I can get all the values of all the cells.

But where would I find the names of the columns?

Please note that I'm not asking for a code example. The last person who saw this question thought I was asking for code and so marked this question as a duplicate. But I'm actually asking for the name of the XML file where I can find information. Knowing the correct file, I will build my own approach, which won't use XSSFReader or anything related to it. Nothing from POI.

Comment: In Excel there are not specific "column names". Maybe you mean the texts in the first row of the columns to be the "column names". If so, they are in `/xl/sharedStrings.xml`. You have it already with `SharedStringsTable sst = xssfReader.getSharedStringsTable();`.

Comment: Thank you. I will hit sst with toString, and also look in the files

Comment: I would not trying around. [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html) is documented. [SharedStringsTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/SharedStringsTable.html) is a class with methods which can be used. And there is also an [Example](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) how to use XSSF and SAX (Event API).